# Regex on route group, how?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, url-routing

How do you add an regexp on a `Route::group`? On a normal `Route::verb` you add `->where('segment', 'regex')` to the end, but how do you do it on a group?

I would like something like this (not working as `->where()` on `Route::group` is invalid):

```
Route::group(['prefix' => '{profileId}'], function(){
    Route::get('/', [
        'as' => 'profileShow',
        'uses' => 'ProfileController@getShow'
    ]);

    Route::post('ny-anvandare', [
        'as' => 'profileAccessNew',
        'uses' => 'ProfileController@getAccess'
    ]);
})->where('profileId', '[0-9]+');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use the Enhanced Router package by Jason Lewis: https://github.com/jasonlewis/enhanced-router

It introduces much requested enhancements to Laravel's Routing components, including regex filters on groups.

I am not 100% sure if it is Laravel 4.1-ready, but if you're using 4.0, you should be good to go.